# Elasticsearch and Python Bool Query using Should and a List

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am currently writing a script that uses python and the elasticsearch module to read in a list of IP addresses and then create a query to be used.

Below is some code that should explain what I am trying to do:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(["serveraddress"])


with open(ipfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    ipList = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

query = {"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"term":{"source":ipList}},{"term":{"destination":ipList}}]}}}

results = es.search(index=index, body=query)
```

However, once I execute this, I get the following error:

```
<type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('string indices must be integers',))
```

After testing the query, it appears the issue is with using lists inside of multiple terms and strings.

Does anybody have a workaround for this? Again this script is suppose to read a file filled with IP addresses which could very in length.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. There may be an easier way to do this but below is what worked for me.

```
with open(ipfile, 'r') as f:
            ipList = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]
shouldQuery = []
[shouldQuery.append({'term':{'source':'{}'.format(ip)}}) for ip in ipList]
[shouldQuery.append({'term':{'destination':'{}'.format(ip)}}) for ip in ipList]
query = {'query':{'bool':{'should':[shouldQuery]}}}
```

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues. If someone has a more simple way of doing this please let the community know:)